# Scale Factor meaning

Tags: education

I need to do this fast because tomorrow I got math exam and suddenly my friend said that scale factor is tested (Basic ones)None of my friend understands...But my question is

1.If I were to get a scale of $x:y$,will my scale factor be $\frac{x}{y}$ or $\frac{y}{x}$?

2.Must scale factor be bigger than 1?

That is the only 2 question I need.Thanks!If you can give me more advice,I would be glad!Even Google search only give examples.Not directly to this question :/

Comment: @user222031 Ill look up now.But ratio?Scale factor is a bit more of fractions.Ill check if they included it

Comment: I think they are the same thing, and I don't think scale factors is a common term.

Comment: @user222031 I see,looks like I dont even need search anymore since you say that.It's too clear now.But one more question.If a question says enlarging by a scale factor of 0.5,would it mean reducing by 2 times?